# Showing occurences in JS array, returns correct in console but undefined on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

So as the title indicates, I'm having some issues displaying on an HTML page the amount of occurences of each integer in a randomized array. I'm hoping to get it display "X appears N times" or something along that sort, but when I add a string it appears as undefined in the console as well when the correct value shows if I just put the values alone. I'll demonstrate what I mean :

```js
function Display(id, content) { // this works fine just included for context
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.innerHTML = content;
}

function GetOccurences(amt) { // here is where I have my issue

  count = {};
  arr.forEach(function(amt) {
    count[amt] = count[amt] + 1 || 1
    return count, amt;
  });

  console.log(count); // Displays correct date in console, though no room to insert dialogue 
  Display("occursId", count); //Displays undefined on HTML page

}

GetOccurences("test")
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance for any and all help

Comment: Why do you have `return count, amt;`? `forEach()` doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback function. Also, you can't return multiple values in JS.

Comment: Passing an object to `Display()` will just display `[Object object]`. You should pass a string.

Comment: `GetOccurrences()` isn't using its parameter, because you're reusing the variable `amt` in the `forEach()` callback function.

Comment: What's the point of the `test` argument to `GetOccurrences` if you're counting the occurrences of integers?

Comment: I didn't do the test .. I think someone edited and added that there though I'm confused as to why.

Comment: Your original code was missing a call to the function. The person who edited it into a Stack Snippet added the call, and made up an argument. Since the function never uses the argument, he just put an arbitrary value there.

Answer (score 0):

`getOccurrences()` should take `arr` as a parameter, not `amt`.

Before calling `Display()`, you need to convert the returned value to a string that contains your formatted results.

```js
function Display(id, content) {
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.innerHTML = content;
}

function GetOccurences(arr) {

  const count = {};
  arr.forEach(function(num) {
    count[num] = count[num] + 1 || 1
  });

  const formatted = Object.entries(count).map(([num, amt]) => 
    `${num} appears ${amt} times`).join('<br>');
  Display("occursId", formatted);
}

GetOccurences([1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 2, 5])
```

```html
<div id="occursId"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! .. I need to brush up on reformatting strings from objects, just learning about objects this week so it's a bit of a process but practice makes progress